# At what time (BST) are interest rate futures settled daily on Eurex Exchange?

Tags: futures, bond-futures, eurex

ie, what is the earliest time can I expect to see settle prices for all interest rate futures (ie, BUXL future, GILT future) on Eurex exchange? Is it 15:00 local time just like it is on CME ?

Answer (score 1):

On normal days the settlement time for bond futures such as Bund, Buxl, etc. on the Eurex Exchange is 17:15 CET (Central European Time). The settlement is calculated from the volume-weighted average of all transactions between 17:14 and 17:15. [Source: www.eurexchange.com]. Generally within a few minutes (in my experience between 17:15 and 17:20) the settlement price is disseminated through the usual channels, such as Reuters, Bloomberg etc.

An exception occurs on the last day of trading for a particular maturity. On such a day (which occurs once a quarter) the expiring future stops trading at 12:30 CET, and the settlement is calculated at that time.